# how to scroll from start element using id?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have this example in [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q6s3f7Ld/)

The problem is when clicking on "description" and "review" link have different behavior (with .affix header class on and off).

```
data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="80"
```

How can i fix when clicking those links to start content from 1 ("Desc content1" and "Rev content1") ???

Comment: The behavior of the link is always the same, it moves the anchor to the top of the page. The difference is that when your menu is fixed to the top it covers the first two contents. Try adding padding to the top of description and review that is equal to the height of your navbar.

Answer (score 0):

A quick and dirty fix, I modified the code a bit to detect the height of the header and the tabs.  There might be some more CSS changes that you need to cater for the header and tabs being position fixed. Check out this [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/54g1nur6/4/)

```
$('#revBtn').on('click', function () {
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $('#descBtn').removeClass('active');
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#rev").position().top - $('header').outerHeight() - $('.nav-tabs').outerHeight()
    }, 'slow');
});

$('#descBtn').on('click', function () {
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $('#revBtn').removeClass('active');
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#desc").position().top - $('header').outerHeight() - $('.nav-tabs').outerHeight()
    }, 'slow');
});
```

Comment: when click the tabs with header fixed it starts from 2 not from 1.